# Recursion Error with Surface_polygon

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having a recursion error that I think is very basic but I'm not seeing the problem, although I think it's in the stopping condition.
Basically, I have a list of lists, where each list is a floor with around 30 points. I'm doing a recursion that goes to each floor and makes a surface polygon in each and then i make an extrusion with each surface_polygon in another function.

Down below is the code and the error message, he makes me the 75 floors I want to make but once the list of floors is empty he errors.

```
    def pisos_generico(list_lists):
        if list_lists == []:
            pass
        else:
            return surface_polygon (list_lists[0]) + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])

    def pisos (list_lists):
        return extrusion(pisos_generico (list_lists)
```

This is the error code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
    547, in <module>
        pisos (xy(0,0), 1.41, 0.02, 75)
      File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
    529, in pisos
        return extrusion(pisos_generico (piso_pisos_rodados (lista, n_andares, p, a, a_torcao)), vz(0.3))
      File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 503, in pisos_generico
        return surface_polygon (list_lists[0]) + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
      File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 503, in pisos_generico
        return surface_polygon (list_lists[0]) + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
      File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 503, in pisos_generico
        return surface_polygon (list_lists[0]) + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
       [Previous line repeated 72 more times]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'surface_polygon' and 'NoneType'
```

---

Updated version:

```
def pisos (p, a, a_torcao, n_andares):
     return pisos_generico (lista_listas)

def pisos_generico(list_lists):
    if list_lists == []:
        []    
    else:
        return [extrusion(surface_polygon (list_lists[0]), vz(0.3))] + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
```

And the new Error message, pretty much like the old one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
548, in <module>
    pisos (xy(0,0), 1.41, 0.02, 75)
  File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
530, in pisos
    return pisos_generico (lista_listas)
  File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
503, in pisos_generico
    return [extrusion(surface_polygon (list_lists[0]), vz(0.3))] + 
pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
  File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
503, in pisos_generico
    return [extrusion(surface_polygon (list_lists[0]), vz(0.3))] + 
pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
  File "D:\Universidade\3o Ano\PCA\Projeto\First Try Base Planta 2.py", line 
503, in pisos_generico
    return [extrusion(surface_polygon (list_lists[0]), vz(0.3))] + 
pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
  [Previous line repeated 72 more times]
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Function implicitly return `None` if you return noting. This happens on

```
def pisos_generico(list_lists):
    if list_lists == []:
        pass
    else:
        return surface_polygon (list_lists[0]) + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
        #                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        #                                                     empty => returns None

   # exactly here on list_lists == [] is None returned
```

You probably need something like:

```
def pisos_generico(list_lists):
    if list_lists == []:                          # you can delete the ``... == []: pass``
        pass                                      # part and make the next one
    elif len(list_lists) == 1:                    # a normal if instead of elif
        return surface_polygon (list_lists[0])    # just make sure you do not call it with    
    else:                                         # an empty list to start with
        return surface_polygon (list_lists[0]) + pisos_generico(list_lists[1:])
```

Comment: Hi, I made some changes because I'd like to put all the floors into a list, so I can call them whenever I want. Your advice while it makes perfect sense It didn't solve the problem: there's something else causing the Nonetype but I can't figure out what. I left my code updated in the original post, sinc ein this comment section I can't put it right